# RSA algorithm assignment

Tags: rsa

Alice wants to share a symmetric key with Bob. She encrypts the small (64-bit) secret key $K$ with Bob’s public RSA key $(n,e)$ by padding it with zeroes to 2048 bits (the length of n) and computing
$$C\gets(\text{0..0}\|K)^e\bmod n$$
Thereupon, she sends $C$ to Bob. Discuss either why this key exchange is secure or describe an efficient attack that can recover $K$ with far less than $2^{64}$ operations.

Comment: Hints: a) consider what happens when $e$ is small; say 3, 5, or 17, which are reasonable choices when proper padding is used. $\;$  b) regardless of $e$, consider odds that $K$ can be written as the product of two integers neither exceeding, say, $2^{40}$.

Comment: Hint: if they signify the RSA encryption operation of $M$ as $RSA(M)$, then we have $RSA(A) \times RSA(B) = RSA(A \times B)$ (where $\times$ is modulo $n$).  How could you take advantage of that?

Comment: What [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) does that use? $\;$

Comment: Why the heck would you have to left pad with zeros if the next operation turns the binary input into a big endian number? It would immediately remove all the zero bytes again. Then the question itself: that discussion if it is secure or not is completely irrelevant because of the next question.